# Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines: use tag instead of branch

Tags: azure, deployment, tags, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two Azure DevOps yaml pipeline one for build (artifact, add tag to repository) and another for deployment. I use tags [image: UsingTag] in deploy pipeline. When the deployment pipeline starts it uses the correct repository build version but still consume/usess the latest artifact from build.
[image: BuildNumber]. It is also downloading twice the artifacts.
[image: DownloadArtifacts]

trigger:

- none

pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest
demands: vstest

name: $(ReleaseNumber)

resources:
pipelines:
- pipeline: XXXX
source: 'XXXX-CI'

- stage: PersonalDevStage
  dependsOn:

  - UpdateBuildNumber
    jobs:
- deployment: DeployFunctions
  displayName: Deploy Functions
  environment: ${{ parameters.EnvironmentName }}
  strategy:
  runOnce:
  deploy:
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  clean: true

  ```
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        buildType: 'specific'
        project: '$(System.TeamProjectId)'
        definition: '7'
        buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
        pipelineId: '${{ parameters.PipelineBuildNumber }}'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        targetPath: '${{ parameters.ArtifactPath }}'
        downloadPath: '${{ parameters.ArtifactPath }}'


    - template: 'DeployFunctions.yml'
      parameters:
        SubscriptionName: '${{ parameters.AzureSubscriptionName }}'
        SubscriptionId: '${{ parameters.AzureSubscriptionId }}'
        AzureLocation: '${{ parameters.AzureLocation }}'
        StageName: '${{ parameters.StageName }}'
        SubStageName: '${{ parameters.SubStageName }}'
        StageSuffix: ${{ parameters.StageSuffix }}
        ARMTemplatePathHosting: '${{ parameters.ArtifactPath }}/ARMScripts/Plan.json'
        ARMTemplatePathXXX: '${{ parameters.ArtifactPath }}/ARMScripts/odmod.json'
        XXXStatsFunctionsPath: '${{ parameters.ArtifactPath }}/drop/XXXService.zip'
  ```